# I get this error when I try to add TapGestureRecognizer to my UIImageView : Unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: swift3, xcode8, ios10, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have this DiaryCell (collectionviewcell) class, and I am trying to add a gesture recognizer in that class to call the method of a  collectionViewController, which is a different class.

```
class DiaryCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    //imageview for favorite button
    let favoriteImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "favorite_gray")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        return imageView
    }()

    //imageview for menu button
    let menuImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "menu_image")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()
}
```

I have tried different strategies, but I am not able to add the gesture recognizer to menuImageView. I have tried doing this, where HomeCollectionViewController is the controller where I want to handle the action when image is tapped.

```
imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: HomeCollectionViewController.self, action: #selector(HomeCollectionViewController.menuBarPressed))
```

Comment: `setupViews()` ? what does that do.

Comment: it sets up the constraints for the whole cell. I have no idea why the line at the bottom of my question doesn't work.

Comment: Have you added the TapGestureDelegate. Needs to set it to the `HomeCollectionViewController`

Comment: @SachinVas I am not sure what you mean. Can you please elaborate a little? I am sorry, but sometimes it requires me more information to understand some stuff.

Comment: `let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: HomeCollectionViewController.self, action: #selector(HomeCollectionViewController.menuBarPressed) gesture.delegate = HomeCollectionViewController.self imageView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)`

Comment: I tried that. Did you mean the last line of my question by any chance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134455/discussion-between-vandan-a-patel-and-sachin-vas).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that while your code is legal and compiles, it's wrong.

You are setting up your gesture to be send to a type not an instance. You need to set the target as the actual instance of `HomeCollectionViewController`

One way to achieve this is by setting a weak reference to your controller in the cell.

```
class DiaryCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var tapGesture:UITapGestureRecognizer?
    weak var gestureTarget: HomeCollectionViewController? {
        didSet {
            setupGestures()
        }
    }

    func setupGestures() {

        if let tapGesture = tapGesture {
            removeGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
            self.tapGesture = nil
        }

        if let gestureTarget = gestureTarget {
            let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: gestureTarget, action: #selector(HomeCollectionViewController.menuBarPressed))
            addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
            tapGesture = gesture
        }

    }

}
```

You would probably set the `gestureTarget` in your `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` method

While this solves your problem its not a good way to approach things and you should look up how to use delegation as a coding pattern.